# PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. facing issue in eclipse version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am struggling with this issue and not able to install Spring plugin through eclipse marketplace even after setting up corporate proxy.
I already performed below steps:

1. Tried too many eclipse version compatible with JDK now I have eclipse Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0) and JDK1.8.0_331
2. Set JAVA_HOME path as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_331\bin in user variables
3. Tried to modified eclipse.ini file to and set -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_331\lib\security\cacerts under -vmargs
4. Added -vm
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_331\bin\javaw.exe in eclipse.ini file and restarted eclipse.
5. Also cross checked configuration for -vm and -vmargs in eclipse -> installation details -> configuration and seems to be good.

After performing all above steps still I am getting same issue of eclipse marketplace. Attached is the error snapshot. If anybody can assist/suggest it would be really helpful.
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you need specifically run Eclipse with Java 1.8? As a rule of a thumb your IDE should run using the latest Java version available, you can change what JDK you compile with in it's settings if you need to. You even found the setting in eclipse.ini that allows it to start with a different JDK than the one on PATH!

Comment: Thank you for your help and response.  I have tried on jdk-11.0.16 also but still same issue persist.

Answer (score -1):

There is a chance your organization is using an SSL intercepting proxy. It can also be titled as SSL inspection or man-in-the-middle-attack.

You will either have to tell Eclipse to no longer check the certificates (and trust blindly - not recommended) or to add the server's (or proxy's) CA certificate to Eclipse's truststore.